# I'm newbie to .NET. I have some doubts in understanding terminologies .What is the difference between .NET core and .NET 5?

Tags: c#

.NET Framework only supports the Windows platform.
.NET core supports Windows, Linux, and Mac OS.
.NET Core will not support andriod and ios.

.NET 5 supports Windows,MAC OS,LINUX,Anroid and IOS.

Am i correct in all the above points?

Comment: You might want to accept a reply as an answer and possible post more comments if you need to know more.

Answer (score 4):

This is **not** a precise answer but good for a newcomer, prone to be confused and overwhelmed by the official and exhausting information.

There are two parallell platforms.

1. .NET Framework
2. .NET Core

.NET 5 will merge those two into a single one. So .NET 5 is the next generation (sort of) of .NET Core. But it't also quite more as well. As for the supporting OS's, you're not wrong but you're not quite right, neither. It's not precisely a yes/no issue. It may support certain features of some OS differently well and corresponding to your need or not. It's a jungle and it's constantly changing.

Now, you might have specific considerations like *which should you learn at the moment*. On that question - you should go with .NET 5. (Unless there's a specific reason, e.g. job requirement, for you to go with .NET Core 3.x, which is the current version, or .NET Framework 4.x, which is its current dito).

You may also wonder *how big is the difference between the platforms*. To that, there are two answers. For me, it's humongous - basically day and night. For you, assuming the proficiency level suggested by your question, it's negligible - you won't notice even if it kicks you in the nuts. It's a good thing. You can't pick wrongly.

Another issue might be *whether you will be able to deploy your product the requested way*. You will be. However, picking another framework may make that easier. It also may make that harder. Bottom line is, you won't know until you're there but the general purpose frameworks will never block you.

Comment: There is also Mono, which IMHO is also being merged into dotnet 5+.

Comment: It's also worth noting that most of the effort invested into a codebase on platformX will be retained if you need to change to platformY. Ie the code for one is largely the same as the code for the other.

Comment: @Aron You're sort of right. Mono is already (sort of) merged into the .NET Core (please note the sort of, I want to be understandable for the OP at the cost of certain inaccuracy). And it's perfectly correct that MS hopes to merge **any and all** of the tech sprouts (EF, MVC, WebAPI, Xamarin etc.) into a single platform. Great idea! I can't wait to see how far it takes before we have .NET 5 (basic), .NET 5 (desktop) etc. I hope I'm wrong. (There's first time for everything.)

Comment: @CallumMorrisson You are technically correct but there's a pitfall in what you say. While the code retained will work (largely), we should re-code when migrating. Otherwise, we'll just keep the old style and not use the cool nice features. I have colleagues who are "C# devs with Java background". Good coders and the program runs well. Do they use properties (instead of get/set-methods)? Do they use LINQ? Take a guess...   :)

Comment: OMG. I hate non-idiomatic C#. My personal pet peeve is when they have .Close(). Now I have to have a try finally block!

Comment: @KonradViltersten I whole heartedly agree with that sentiment, I've lately been working with a system where a lot of the core libraries were written against .Net 2.0 when it was brand new. It's been.. an exercise in restraint. My point though, is more in the context of a junior being worried about where to start their journey into .Net; addressing that FOMO of picking the wrong starting point. In that, it really doesn't matter, if you find out you need to change platform half way through a project, you won't lose much in the transition.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson Ah, I missed that point, slightly. In that case, yes, I agree with that entirely. A personal, unsolicited reflection here. I've encountered countless exchanges where different developers had diameterally opposite statements. Once they sit down and explain what's mean by what, in which context and under what pre-assumptions, they "always" land into the same spot. (Not precisely always because some jackasses with huge, fragile egos will get prestigey and defensive. But almost always.)

Comment: @Aron It's sometimes argued that *it's tech agnostics* and *C# and Java share syntax*. Well, by that logic, French and Swedish share alphabet and originate largely from Latin and Greek, so I guess I can speak both...

Answer (score 0):

.NET 5 is a combined platform which includes libraries and frameworks from the following:

1. .NET Framework
2. .NET Core
3. Xamarin

For Cross-platform based development, the .NET Core framework versions 1.0 to 3.1 covers development of web apps, windows forms apps, server based apps, mobile apps and cloud hosted apps.

ASP.NET Core is the open-source version of ASP.NET, that runs on macOS, Linux, and Windows. Versions are from 1.1 to 3.1 within .NET Core and version 5 for .NET 5.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/what-is-aspnet-core

ASP.NET is the windows version of ASP.NET, a platform that allows development of web applications hosted on windows servers. Versions are from 1.x to 4.x.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet

The Xamarin platform (not part of .NET Core) allows cross-platform Android and IOS mobile development and is included as part of the .NET 5 platform.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin

For Windows platform based development, the .NET Framework versions 1.0 to 4.8 covers development of windows client and server applications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/overview

Due to the confusion with renaming some of the .NET Core frameworks to .NET 5 frameworks, Microsoft has kept the name "Core" in some of it's technologies.

For example, ASP.NET Core 3.1 keeps it's Core name with the new ASP.NET Core 5 framework instead of confusing it with ASP.NET 5 or ASP.NET MVC 5, which are still in use by many developers.

Another example is the .NET Framework based ORM provider Entity Framework 5, and the .NET Core based ORM provider Entity Framework Core 5, both of which keep their names to avoid confusion within the .NET 5 platform.

Depending on what your application development goals are (cross-platform, windows, mobile, server etc.) you can choose the project templates and libraries from .NET Core or .NET Framework compatible packages within .NET 5 (and beyond) that will achieve your goals.

Comment: I always regarded Xamarin as a part of .NET Framework (it was so in the first version when MS bought up the shares in Xamarin). Do they consider Xama as a separate platform now? Not just a (huge and powerful) library?

Comment: The Xamarin framework uses the Mono libraries, which are a cross-platform cut-down version of .NET Framework for mobile devices. So if you know how to develop in .NET framework, then the Xamarin framework should be straightforward to learn. Mono is a cross-platform version of .NET Framework that Microsoft build around 20 years ago before the full .NET Framework was released. Before Microsoft bought out Xamarin in 2016 it was a licensed development platform, now it it free and open source.